# Select data rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code:

```
select *
from dbo.splitstringPBD((
    select DATA
    from LAS_TABLE tb
    inner join LAS_T_APK apk on apk.FID_CIF_LAS = tb.FID_CIF_LAS 
    where ID_APK = 123
))
```

Result:

[image]

I only want row 4 which is 165 m2

How do I retrieve the data according to the rows I want?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Do you mean only row 4? Or all rows up to an including row 4?

Comment: What is `splitstringPBD`? your custom [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? Take a look at the example [Split comma-separated value string in a colum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-split-comma-separated-value-string-in-a-column) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *, 0 as order_num
from dbo.splitstringPBD((
    select DATA
    from LAS_TABLE tb
    inner join LAS_T_APK apk on apk.FID_CIF_LAS = tb.FID_CIF_LAS 
    where ID_APK = 123
))
order by order_num offset 3 rows fetch next 1 rows only
```

This will fetch only row 4 (offset start with 0, so to get row number 3 use offset 2, etc).

In fact, the order of the results returned from your query above is currently unknown, so change the `order_num` into the column you desire for ordering.

Comment: The order_num can be anything honestly. You can set it as empty string, or give it any static value. It is there just so the ordering of rows you get is what you see without order by, so it wont mess up your query order. The key for your question  is the **offset** and the **fetch** that requires **order by** to work.

Comment: I am well aware if it dear sir @DaleK but without knowing the contain of function **splitstringPBD** (that i assume is function that returns a table) at all, its safe to assume he have proper ordering in it. But it is nice to note for people know that the order is in fact, as you state, is unknown. Thanks dear sir.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thanks @DaleK for the correction.